# how align expandable divs with different heights?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**My initial layout:**

This divs are "col-md-4" classin bootstrap 
[image]

*If I expand the div number 3* :
[image]

My question is there a way to have this layout as a result (applicable if we have more than 4 divs and expanding 2 or 3 at a time ):

[image]

Comment: Check out the [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) library

Comment: Depending browser support needs, you could use pure css solution using [css column](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/). Just that divs would be placed in vertical order

Comment: Yes it seems a duplicate. Thank you